# Using external transactions within test suite

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, python-unittest

[External transactions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/orm/session_transaction.html#joining-a-session-into-an-external-transaction-such-as-for-test-suites).

I want to commit a model or models to the database and roll them back after each test.  The pure `sqlalchemy` implementation (at the bottom) works the way I expect.  However, the `flask-sqlalchemy` implementation fails to rollback the committed models after each test.

How can I bind `flask-sqlalchemy`'s scoped session to the engine's connection?

Generic `flask` app:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite://'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class A(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

`flask-sqlalchemy` testcase (doesn't roll back):

```
from app import *
from unittest import TestCase


class Test(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.connection = db.engine.connect()
        self.transaction = self.connection.begin()

        options = dict(bind=self.connection, binds={})
        self.session = db.create_scoped_session(options=options)
        db.session = self.session

        self.addCleanup(self.cleanup)

    def cleanup(self):
        self.transaction.rollback()
        self.connection.close()
        self.session.remove()

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        db.create_all()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        pass

    def test_1(self):
        a = A()
        db.session.add(a)
        db.session.commit()

        assert len(db.session.query(A).all()) == 1

    def test_2(self):
        assert len(db.session.query(A).all()) == 0  # len is 1
```

`sqlalchemy` testcase (works):

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from unittest import TestCase


Base = declarative_base()


class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


class Test(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.connection = e.connect()
        self.transaction = self.connection.begin()

        # Begin scoped session
        factory = sessionmaker(bind=self.connection)
        self.session = scoped_session(factory)

        self.addCleanup(self.cleanup)

    def cleanup(self):
        self.session.close()
        self.transaction.rollback()
        self.connection.close()

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        global e

        e = create_engine("sqlite://")
        Base.metadata.create_all(e)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        pass

    def test_1(self):
        a = A()
        self.session.add(a)
        self.session.commit()

        assert len(self.session.query(A).all()) == 1

    def test_2(self):
        assert len(self.session.query(A).all()) == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and perhaps my fix is the same as yours.

The this is now my setUp and tearDown:

```
import unittest
from my_app import db

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.connection = db.engine.connect()
        self.trans = self.connection.begin()
        db.session.configure(bind=self.connection, binds={})

    def tearDown(self):
        self.trans.rollback()
        self.connection.close()
        db.session.remove()
```

What actually did it for me was adding the:

```
binds={}
```

I haven't really investigated why this fixes it but it did for me. Would love to hear if anyone knows why the empty dict to bind fixes the problem.

Comment: What version of flask-sqlalchemy are you running?  I get AttributeError: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute 'configure'.

Comment: Im using flask-sqlalchemy 2.2